# How to prevent MoboGenie popups in Chrome?

Tags: browser

I browse around with many tabs open. Frequently, an ok/cancel dialog "MoboGenie - Play Now" pops up for attention. The host (of the popup) site keeps the dialog hidden till it pops up for attention.

I find it difficult to single out sites which host this popup. None of them host suspicious or intrusive advertisements otherwise.

Comment: +1 this has been annoying me a lot lately seems particularly prevalent in the ad networks used by some webcomics.

Comment: Have you considered rooting your device? Then you have plenty of possibilities to get rid of almost all kind of ads, everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

there is an application you can download for rooted devices called AdAway. 
 it's not in the market, but if you don't have a problem with installing third party apks, this is a complete advertisement blocker for both in-app and browser.

https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers, like [Google's Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en), have built in pop up blockers. Now, if you surf around and you get a auto pop up like this, a message will show on the bottom of the screen asking if you would like to display it. This would greatly reduce the MoboGenie you are seeing. Also, Chrome is a pretty sweet browser with many other features. If you don't like it, [FireFox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) and [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&hl=en) have--to my knowledge--built in pop up blockers.

Comment: In dolphin, `Block pop up windows` is checked but still the  `mobo genie ` pop -up is coming. Especially in sites hosting mp3 songs.

Answer (score -1):

you can use popup blocker "Ad Block" in chrome or "ABP- AdBlock Plus"
for firefox.

Comment: Last time I checked, the Ad Block plugin in Chrome didn't work in Chrome for Android. Does it work now? How do you install the plugin in Chrome for Android?